# If the product of closed sets is closed in the product topology shouldn't {(0,0)} be closed in $A^1 \times A^1$ zariski topology.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, product-space, zariski-topology

I am not sure what is incorrect about the statement.

If the product of closed sets is closed in the product topology shouldn't {(0,0)} be closed in $A^1 \times A^1$ zariski topology, i.e singletons should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things :

- (let us assume the base field is algebraically closed) whenever $a$ and $b$ are closed points in $\mathbb{A}^1$, $(a,b)$ is indeed closed in $\mathbb{A}^2=\mathbb{A}^1\times \mathbb{A}^1$
- the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A^2}$ is not the product topology, it is finer. For example $\{y-x^2=0\}$ is not closed under the product topology but it is under the Zariski topology.

Comment: Why is it not closed under the product topology?

Comment: Proper closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1$ are finite, so closed subsets of the product are also finite, or of the form $\mathbb{A^1}\times \mathrm{finite}$. $\{y-x^2\}$ is not.

Comment: My issue is I am not sure what this has to do with topology. In the case $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \{0\}$ which is closed. Couldn't we just project $y=x^2$ on to the x-axis.

Comment: @benhuni I am confused what you are asking, but it definitely has to do with topology; you're trying to figure out if a set is open or closed.

Comment: maybe the confusion is that you are assuming that continuous maps take closed sets to closed sets, but this is not true (continuous means inverse images of closed sets are closed)

Comment: I am asking if two sets are topologically equivalent. Do both sets need to find closed sets corresponding to $Z(y-x^2)$. This is not clear to me, I believe that all we need to find was a one set with a correspondence then a homeomorphism

Comment: @benhuni first of all: two subsets being homeomorphic does not imply that any of them is closed in the ambient space. Secondly what makes you think that the projection is closed/open/quotient map? One of those has to be true for your claim to make sense. But we are not considering product topology here, so standard properties of projection don't hold. And in this case none of them hold, and vanxoo gave you the proof.

Comment: @freakish this statement is not true. What he has proved is the solution set cannot be closed in $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$. What I am asking is whether topologically this statement is not true! Prove to me that there does not exist homeomorphism.

Comment: @benhuni I don't understand what you are saying. What is not true? What do you mean by "topologically not true"? Homeomorphism between what exactly? And why does it matter? Even if the solution set is homeomorphic to $A^1$, so what? This is a different, unrelated question.

Comment: @freakish don't worry I have completed the statement. What we are trying to prove is that there cannot exist a homeomorphism. Or a topological difference is closed sets. What he showed was a solution set.

Comment: @benhuni $Z(y-x^2)$ is homeomorphic to $A^1$. Because both are of same cardinality and both have cofinite topology. But this is due to the specific choice of $y-x^2$ polynomial. For example $Z(y^2-x^2)$ is no longer homeomorphic to $A^1$, because it is not cofinite, assuming underlying field is infinite.

Comment: @freakish my argument there must exist a homeomorphism such that $Z(x-y^2)$,  is closed in $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$. Then formulate a contradiction The fact that no one see's anything wrong with this answer baffles me!

Comment: @benhuni one last time: homeomorphism between what? Existence of some random homeomorphism **has nothing to do** with the question whether a subset is closed or not. For example $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ but it doesn't make it closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Again: these are unrelated things. There's nothing wrong with the answer.